# Bushound alternative for Linux for SCSI logging

Tags: linux, windows, logs, scsi, alternatives

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good solution to logging specific SCSI device traffic on Linux? Does anyone knew of a comprable Linux alternative to Window's Bushound?

I have looked at already increasing the SCSI logging level, but that increases the logging for all SCSI devices.  Also, I only see the HEX value of the CDB being sent from an initiator to a target, but I not the response in HEX from the target back to the initiator in the logs (Syslogs, kernlogs, dmesg).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible to patch scsi_logging to apply only to some devices, but can you clarify what you mean about the responses?